# iTunes Connect icon rendering

Tags: cocoa, xcode, app-store-connect

Upon submitting an OS X application to the Mac App Store via iTunes, I've noticed that viewing the application icon in iTunes Connect shows the icon with rounded corners and dropshadows. This is strange because when viewing application in the Mac App Store it's clear that the rounded corners are entirely optional.

Is there something I should have added to my Info.plist file in order to stop this from happening (similar to the UIPrerenderedIcon key in iOS products), or is this just an oddity of the iTunes Connect website? The icon renders correctly in Finder and via the Activity screen in Xcode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the App Store renders icons like this by default. It has no impact on the App Store rendering on the customer facing site.